# I need to get a handle on the window object in firefox 3.6 extension before any code is executed

Tags: javascript, firefox, plugins

from a ff 3.6 plugin I want to get notified every time a new window object is created before any JS on the page has run - I tried the "load" event but it seems to be too late, some JavaScript has already been executed by the time I get a handle on the object and I need to be in before any JS is run, does anyone have any ideas please?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to listen for the [`content-document-global-created`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/Observer_Notifications#Documents) notification, that's exactly what you are asking for - a window has been set up but no JavaScript code had a chance to execute yet. This is supported starting with Firefox 3.6.6.

You need to use [nsIObserverService](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/XPCOM_Interface_Reference/nsIObserverService) and register your observer for this topic. When your observer is called the subject will be the newly created window.